# ReactiveSpringSecurity role mapping

Tags: spring, security, keycloak, reactive

Based on this example https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/11/spring-cloud-gateway-with-openid-connect-and-token-relay I'm trying to use Spring Gateway, the latest version of Spring Security and Keycloak. Behind the Gateway there is a static application that I want to limit access to. I managed to configure everything so that authentication works. However, I am unable to validate the role correctly. Spring Security does not read it from the token and always assigns ROLE_USER. Token contains proper role and other parameters like username or scopes are read correctly. How to map a roles using ReactiveSecurity. Below is my configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler(@Value("${postLogoutRedirectUrl}") URI postLogoutRedirectUrl, ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        logoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(postLogoutRedirectUrl);
        return logoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(@Value("${securedPaths}") String[] securedPaths, ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                            OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler) {

        http.oauth2Login();
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(securedPaths).hasRole("admin")
                .anyExchange().permitAll();
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```